# Errors using Microsoft jQuery vsdoc 1.7.1 CDN with Visual Studio 2010

Tags: jquery, visual-studio-2010

I get the following JavaScript errors when using jQuery vsdoc with VS 2010. The Errors go away if I remove the vsdoc.js line.
I tried to add `var rootjQuery = jQuery(document);` but some new errors pops up. I don't want to keep patching that way.

```
Line: 68
Error: 'rootjQuery' is undefined
Line: 8
Error: Object doesn't support this property or method

<head>
    <title>Index</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.7.1.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.7.1-vsdoc.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {

        });
    </script>
</head>
```

**SOLVED**

I found the answer. Just swap the order of jquery and vsdoc script tag.

```
<head>
    <title>Index</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.7.1-vsdoc.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.7.1.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {

        });
    </script>
</head>
```

Comment: Why are you sending the vsdoc down to the client?

Comment: @StuperUser, the goal is to make doc available in visual studio. In production, it'll be removed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

changing the order stopped the javascript errors

and it did not work with any part of [T4MVC](http://mvccontrib.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=T4MVC)

so I did this

```
 @if (System.Diagnostics.Debugger.IsAttached)
    { 
    <script src="../../Scripts/Mvc3/jquery-1.7-vsdoc.js" type="text/javascript"></script> @* intellisense! *@
     @Html.RelativeJavascript(Links.Scripts.Mvc3.jquery_1_7_js)
     @Html.RelativeJavascript(Links.Scripts.Mvc3.jquery_unobtrusive_ajax_js)
    }
    else
    {
        @Html.RelativeJavascript(Links.Scripts.Mvc3.jquery_1_7_min_js) 
        @Html.RelativeJavascript(Links.Scripts.Mvc3.jquery_unobtrusive_ajax_min_js)  
    }
```

but I only seem to get Intellisense for javascript written on the page (not in my `src=` files)

**EDIT:** 
[based on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff798328.aspx)
found out how to get the intelli-sense in stand-alone files

```
/// <reference path="../Mvc3/jquery-1.7-vsdoc.js" />
```

Also drag and drop from the solution explorer into the `.js` file worked!